# Able to read table header, but not table content

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

So here is what I am trying to do – quite simply really. I have a pdf document that contains data, and I want to extract it using python. This is in the context where I am trying to automate the data extraction from a fixed template that will need to be read in regularly.

I am using the tabula-py package, and reading the data in using the “read_pdf" function. The problem is that it only seems to be reading in part of the table I need… more specifically it is only able to read in the table header. Strangely enough I don’t get this problem if I read the table in using the online tabula tool.

```
# Here is the python code to read table content
df = tb.read_pdf(path+name+'.pdf', encoding='latin-1', area=[416.543,25.398,434.903,582.318],spreadsheet=True,pages=2)

# Here is the tabula online tool script:
java -jar tabula-java.jar  -a 416.543,25.398,434.903,582.318 -p 2 "$1"
```

The former yields

> an object of type « None »

while the later yields:

> 1 2018    Peterbilt   Tracteur routier    Some VIN number 230 000 $

Running the same queries on the header of the table yield results the desired results:

```
# Here is the python code to read table header
df = tb.read_pdf(path+name+'.pdf',encoding='latin-1',area=[397.418,24.633,417.308,583.083],spreadsheet=True,pages=2)

# Here is the tabula online tool script:
java -jar tabula-java.jar  -a 397.418,24.633,417.308,583.083 -p 2 "$1"
```

The former yields

> Empty DataFrame Columns: [Item, Année, Marque, Carrosserie, No série,
>   Valeur actuelle] Index: []

while the latter yields

> Item  Année   Marque  Carrosserie No série    Valeur actuelle

Since tabula-py is just a wrapper around the java package I would have thought that both would behave in exactly the same way. What am I missing?

Windows 10 64-bit
tabula-py v1.0.0
Java v8

Answer (score 4):

Silly me - with all the researching I omitted to read the tabula-py documentation to the very end.

> The result is different from tabula-java. Or, stream option seems not
>   to work appropriately tabula-py set guess option True by default, for
>   beginners. It is known to make a conflict between stream option. If
>   you feel something strange with your result, please set guess=False.

Turns out that this was probably what was happening. Everything now works like a charm.

Comment: is there a downside of always use the guess=False option?

Comment: This worked to me once. But now, using another table, I'm facing this problem again and change the `guess` option didn't work. The PDF I'm working with is a good quality one with OCR rightly applied. I don't know how to solve this. Any guess?